# Нужна ли запятая перед КАК (ТОЛЬКО) , КУДА и КОГДА?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Дело в том, что, когда наступает осень, наша дорога превращается в непролазное болото.
2. Дело в том, что, как только пройдет сильный дождь, наша дорога превращается в непролазное болото.
3. Дело в том, что, куда обратиться по поводу того, что наша дорога  постоянно превращается в непролазное болото , мы не знаем.

Answer (score 4):

Согласно правилам Лопатина, запятая на стыке союзов не ставится, если союз двойной.

Здесь нет двойных союзов, следовательно, все запятые ставятся.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ !